# Nightwatch.js navigate behaves differently across drivers

Tags: nightwatch.js, selenium-firefoxdriver, selenium-iedriver

I want to use Nightwatch.js v.0.9.8 for E2E testing.

My [page object](http://nightwatchjs.org/guide#page-objects):

```
module.exports = {
  url() {
    return path.join(this.api.launchUrl, 'Home/Index');
  }
};
```

My test:

```
module.exports = {
  'Sample 1'(client) {
    client.page.home()
      .navigate()
      .expect.element('body').to.be.present;
  },
  'Sample 2'(client) {
    client.page.home()
      .navigate()
      .expect.element('header').to.be.present;
    client.end();
  }
};
```

This works flawlessly in Chrome.

However in Firefox (geckodriver 0.11.1 x64), `Sample 2` ends up with running at *http://localhost:3535/localhost:3535/Home/Index*.

IE (IEDriverServer 2.53.1 x64) opens with a dialog window:
*Cannot find path 'http:\localhost:3535\Home\Index'. Make sure the path or Internet address is correct.*

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1):

Solved it - my mistake. The problem is that `path.join(this.api.launchUrl, 'Home/Index')` flips slashes. I replaced it with simple string concatenation and it works correctly.